# how to add a attribute value from the last row with another attribute value from current row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Basically i have a table that has the attributes: id, created_at, updated_at, user_id, email, debit, credit, and acctbal. i am use Rails, and i have an add funds button on a page that has account history. if i deposit 50.00 it will properly add a new row in that table and put 50 in the deposit attribute keeping credit null. But the acctbal attribute is also null, i cant figure out how to add the current credit value to the last row's acctbal value in that table.i am using RoR. i will use the same technique for the debit value.  my create method is the following there is no computation for acctbal because i am stuck.

```
def create
#@account = Account.new(account_params)
# @account.save
# respond_with(@account)
@account = Account.new(account_params)
@account.email = current_user.email
@account.user_id = current_user.id
respond_to do |format|
  if @account.save
    format.html { redirect_to accounts_url, notice: 'Thank you and enjoy.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @account }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
  format.json { render json: @account.errors, status::unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

can anyone please help me, fingers are bleeding from trying a bunch of stuff ive found online but to no avail.

Comment: I don't understand, you want to show the amount they are depositing to create their account? I would think you would have a create action to create the account, but a deposit would be done through the update action. Please edit your question with more information. What is your table name and structure?

Comment: Are the `accounts` table rows representing transactions? So if I deposit $50 it would create a new row in `accounts` with my id, the $50 and my current balance? You would need a `before_action` that looks up the last row created with my id, then get that row's balance and add the deposit amount to get my new balance.

Comment: yes the accounts table is more of a transactions table. so when a new row is created whether a credit or debit is taking place the before_action looks up the acctbal attribute of the previous row? how would i make that into a line of code? <%  acctbal.before_action(value) -/+ current.credit/debit(value) %> ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are getting at is this:

```
def credit
  @previous_balance = Account.where('user_id = ?', current_user.id).order(:created_at).last.acctbal
  @account = Account.new(account_params)
  @account.email = current_user.email
  @account.user_id = current_user.id
  @account.acctbal = account_params[:deposit] + @previous_balance 
  respond_to do |format|
    if @account.save
      format.html { redirect_to accounts_url, notice: 'Thank you and enjoy.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @account }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @account.errors, status::unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

As I said in comments above, you are just pulling their last balance from the last created row with their id and adding that to the deposit. Two things to note:
  1) If this is the way you are doing it, you should never `update` a row in this table, or if you do you should use the `updated_at` attribute instead.
  2) You should place an index on the created_at attribute to keep this from being a drag on the DB as the table gets large.

Comment: i see what would be a better approach? basically what the scenario is that a user as an account and they can add funds to the account and when they purchase something it will be deducted from that balance. my reasoning was to have the create action method as the credit function and making a debit action method for the subtraction... mayb i should just make a credit action method and put that code in there and leave create method for an admin user to add a credit/debit row when a need should arise?

Comment: That sounds better to me. I think your better off with actual credit and debit  actions. But you are on the right track, you just needed the code to get the previous balance from the table. I actually like your transaction table idea because it keeps a chronological record of every transaction.